# How to load events onto FullCalendar's calendar on first load?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

How do I get my calendar to render only after the event data has been fetched using outlook REST api.

```
$('#calendarBox').fullCalendar({
            height: 500,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            disableDragging: true,
            editable: false,
            timezone: 'local',
            eventLimit:true,
            views:{
                eventLimit:4
            },
            events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                //This functon executes every time the calendar changes views.
                //the "start" and "end" variables contain the date values
                //for the first and last day visible in the calendar.
                //we need to convert these dates to a formate that the
                //REST query recognizes
             var startString = (start._d).getUTCFullYear() +"-"+
                              ("0" + ((start._d).getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) +"-"+
                              ("0" +(start._d).getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + "T" +
                              ("0" +(start._d).getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
                              ("0" +(start._d).getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" +
                              ("0" +(start._d).getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2)+ "Z";

             var endString = (end._d).getUTCFullYear() +"-"+
                              ("0" + ((end._d).getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) +"-"+
                              ("0" +(end._d).getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + "T" +
                              ("0" +(end._d).getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
                              ("0" +(end._d).getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" +
                              ("0" +(end._d).getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2) +"Z";
                //execute the outlook REST query passing in the token in the header
                var call = $.ajax({
                    url: "https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime="+startString+"&endDateTime=" + endString + "&top=100", 
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true",
                        'Authorization': "Bearer " + accessToken
                    }
                });
                call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
                    var events = [];
                    //loop through the returned events and push them
                    //into the events array that will be displayed in the calendar.
                    for (index in data.value)
                    {
                        events.push({
                                    title: data.value[index].Subject,
                                    start: data.value[index].Start
                                });
                    }
                    callback(events);
                });
                call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
                    alert("Error retrieving events: " + jqXHR.responseText);
                    console.log("error retrieveing events.")
                });                                
            }
        });
```

This is how I initialize the calendar, but at first when loading it on the web page, I will have the calendar rendered without it's events, as can be seen in the screenshot.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RD0K.jpg)

I know it is able to retrieve events from my outlook calendar because if I were to click the buttons on the map such as going to previous month, the calendar would display the events onto it. Perhaps, on first load, the calendar renders faster than it can receive the event data from the outlook REST api? How would I fix this problem.

Comment: have you checked your browser console for any errors, or debugged to see if the initial AJAX request to Outlook is running correctly, and what, if any, response you receive? fullCalendar will normally make a request for events as soon as it is initialised. Perhaps there is some problem with the events for that month. Maybe you don't actually have any events that month???

Comment: There is no error in the browser console. I am sure there are events for that month. Perhaps, my description of the problem is not clear enough so let me try to explain it with an example. When first loading up the web page with the calendar on it, we will have the month view for the month of June.At first the calendar would be empty with no events in it, but if I were to click the button to go the previous month, and then the button to go back to the next month which would bring me back to same month, the month of June, I will be able to see all my events loaded up into the calendar.

Comment: yes I understood it perfectly. So...did you debug as I suggested and watch whether the AJAX call takes place? You can set breakpoints in your JavaScript inside the "events" callback too, to see what is happening. You need to find out where the problem starts. FullCalendar should be firing the "events" callback, but the problem could be anywhere from then onwards - from the code alone it's not really possible to know what that could be, especially if the same code works for other months. As I said, you need to debug.

Comment: BTW, why are you going to such lengths to format your dates for sending to the server? If you just operate directly on `start` and `end` themselves, momentJS provides much easier formatting options than building your string up by hand like that: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Oh wow, the momentJs formatting options do make things a lot more convenient. I am not too experienced in coding however I did try debugging my code. I am sure the AJAX call takes place. The calendar does load events on its first try once in every few tries. I will continue debugging and see if I can fix the problem!

Comment: "I am sure the AJAX call takes place."...in that case, dive into the ajax call (you can click on it in the Network view in your developer tools) and see what exact URL is called, check the HTTP status code which is returned, and what is contained in the Response - you should be expecting the correct parameters to be passed in the URL, a "200 OK" status code, and  valid JSON representing your events in the response. If you find you don't get any of those, or that you're unsure, post your findings into the question (using the "edit" button) and we can maybe help you some more

Comment: The HTTP status code does show "200", the URL parameters entered are correct and I do get the JSON representation of the events in response.

Comment: Can you please show us a sample of the JSON from this initial request then? Perhaps there is something in it which fullCalendar does not like

Comment: I cant actually show the one I receive due to it having sensitive information, but I could show you a sample response of its format. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#GetCalendarView. If you scroll down to the sample response section, that is more or less what I receive.

Comment: according to that data structure you should be writing `start: data.value[index].Start.DateTime` to get the correct value - the actual date is contained with a sub-property of "Start"

Comment: I mocked your endpoint using some of the sample data from the that link, except I changed the dates to match the current month (June 2018), changed your `start:` code to the above, and it works fine, loads the events immediately in the correct location, using the rest of your calendar code: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/756/ . Before I made the change to the `start:` code it was placing the events in the wrong location, presumably due to being unable to parse the start date string correctly.

Comment: I don't see it as a problem. Even if I were to change it to `start: data.value[index].Start.DateTime` everything runs in the exact same manner.

Comment: In that case it's unclear what the issue is because I don't have access to the real data. In principle, the code works. I can only assume that it is somehow not returning data for the correct month, or that there is some other flaw in the data returned by the initial request. Are there any errors or warnings in your browser console after the initial AJAX call runs? Also...you say if you return back to June later, it displays events? Does it make a 2nd AJAX call to do that? If so, do you get the _exact_ same data in the response to that call? You need to keep digging, I can't help much further

Comment: P.S. It _is_ normal that the calendar is initially blank, and then the events appear after a second or two - it depends on how long the initial AJAX request to the Outloook API takes to complete. Again, your network tools will tell you how long it takes. If you don't wait that long before pressing your "next" or "previous" buttons, then that may be a simple explanation for the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Every time you use the buttons to move between different months, it will run a separate AJAX call. I don't think there is any problem with the data I receive or with the AJAX call. Everything works as attended, its just that most of the time when the page first loads up, it will not render the events on to the calendar, however there is an AJAX call made and I do receive the JSON representation of my events from the REST api.

Comment: " most of the time"...so sometimes it displays data the first time, and sometimes not? Is there any difference in the received data when it does work, as compared to when it doesn't? Any difference in the time taken to make the request and get a response? You need to find any possible difference you can which might account for the change of behaviour. _Something_ is causing it, and it's not fullCalendar, because you state say it always appears to make the AJAX request. The issue must be in the response somehow or other. e.g. Perhaps it includes invalid dates, or other unparseable data

Comment: "Every time you use the buttons to move between different months, it will run a separate AJAX call."...actually this not necessarily true - by default fullCalendar will attempt to cache data and minimise the AJAX calls, e.g. if you navigate to a time period which you have viewed before, see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/lazyFetching